# Automatically Show a Popup when it reaches 5PM without a refresh (In real time)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, cookies

I have searched online to get my result but i wasn't able to come across any right solution.
I want my page to automatically show a popup everyday by 5:00PM without refreshing the page.
So, if i visit a page by 4:50Pm or anytime before 5:00PM, Once i am still on that page, it should auto pop up a div without refreshing the page.

I tried using this code but i have to refresh the page before it works which doesn't seem efficient.

```
  $(document).ready(function() {      
      var currentTime = toUTC(new Date());

      var startTime = toUTC(new Date());
      var endTime = toUTC(new Date());

      startTime.setHours(20);
      startTime.setMinutes(10);
      startTime.setSeconds(59);
      endTime.setHours(20);
      endTime.setMinutes(0);
      endTime.setSeconds(0);

      var currentTimez = (currentTime.getHours() + 1);

      if (currentTimez == 20 && currentTime.getMinutes() == 20){
          popup();
      }
  });

  function popup() {
      alert("Thanks")
  }

  function toUTC(inDate) {
      inDate.setMinutes(inDate.getMinutes() + inDate.getTimezoneOffset());
      return inDate;
  }
```

I don't mind if i have to hit the db to get this done or using cookies.

Answer (score 1):

you need to use a timer

```
var current = new Date();
var fivePM = new Date(current.getYear(), current.getMonth(), current.getDayOfMonth());
fivePM.setHour(17);
if (current < fivePM) {
  var diff = fivePM.getTime() - current.getTime();
}
var timerID = setTimeout(popup, diff);
```

Comment: I am not very familiar with javascript. Will this complete code run it successfully every 5PM.? Kindly Modify if wrong.

`<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {  
   var current = new Date();
   var fivePM = new Date(current.getYear(), current.getMonth(), current.getDayOfMonth());
   fivePM.setHour(23);
   if (current < fivePM) {
      var diff = fivePM.getTime() - current.getTime();
   }
   var timerID = setTimeout(popup, diff);

    function popup() {
        alert("Thanks")
    }
  }
</script>`